# Enable PC behind router to be pinged

Tags: windows-7, ping

I've got a Windows 7 PC running a webservice accessing the internet through a standard router. I forwarded the required ports in the router accordingly and was able to use the service successfully from outside.

However, when I try to ping the PC, the request never succeeds. From my point of understanding, pings are performed using ICMP, which is not using ports, so I can't forward a port. Is there any way to get ping requests forwarded to and answered by the PC? (The router itself does not answer pings, apparently, nor do I want it to - I'd really prefer the PC to do that.)

Additionally, the PC does already answer pings from within the local network, but do I need to setup Windows so it also answers requests from outside?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by 'standard router'?  You mention port forwarding which leads me to believe you are talking about a typical consumer router meant for broadband usage.

Routers like this use NAT, to enable them to use a single address from an ISP.  There is probably no way you will be able to forward ICMP to individual machines through a typical cheap-o router.

About the only exception is if your router has a 'DMZ' option.  This option typically allows you to set a single address as a DMZ device.  Any incoming traffic that is not forwarded anywhere else will be forwarded to the DMZ device.

Comment: With a NAT router, even the DMZ will probably not expose the DMZ device to ICMP from the outside as the outside address is still that of the WAN interface of the NAT router and non-ICMP traffic is still NATted to the DMZ device.

Answer (score 2):

With NAT in use, your best bet is to either perform the ping from another device inside the local NAT network or from the NAT router device. Direct ICMP through the NAT is highly unlikely due to the functionality of the NAT.